Facing reindexing elastic search issue
When we run indexing command in the root Magento folder it gives us this error :
Indexer handler is not available: elasticsearch7
When we run the setup:upgrade command:
Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. Verify that the Elasticsearch host and port are configured correctly.
Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1
And this is the my elastic search version:

